# Postgres - data manipulation on a single large table

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have the following postgres table with about **1 million rows**.

**id | underlying | option_symbol | option_type | expiration_date | strike | mid |**

I need to perform the following in under a few seconds :

1. Get all rows with option_type=”foo” and expiration_date > “2017-12-01”
2. Get all rows with option_type=”bar” and expiration_date > “2017-12-01”
3. For each row of query #1, loop over resulting rows of query #2 with the same underlying and expiration_date, and calculate a “spread” derived from values of strike#1 and strike#2.
4. Sort this resulting list of calculated “spreads” and get the best result for each symbol.

**how do I perform the "in query" calculations (spread_profit, spread_distance, spread_max_loss, spread_profit_ratio) in the example below?**

Example:

```
SELECT a.underlying, 
       a.expiration_date, 
       (a.strike - b.strike) as spread_profit, 
       (a.mid - b.mid) as spread_distance, 
       (spread_distance - spread_profit) as spread_max_loss,
       (spread_profit / spread_max_loss) as spread_profit_ratio 
FROM option_data a
   JOIN option_data b ON a.underlying = b.underlying AND a.expiration_date = b.expiration_date
WHERE a.option_type = 'foo' 
  AND b.option_type = 'bar' 
  AND a.expiration_date <= '2017-12-01' 
  AND b.expiration_date <= '2017-12-01' 
GROUP BY a.underlying, a.expiration_date 
ORDER BY spread_profit_ratio DESC
```

Comment: its possible to do in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain of what you're trying to do, but the answer probably looks something like this:

```
select a.underlying
, a.expiration_date
, max(a.strike - b.strike) as spread
from mytable a
join mytable b on a.underlying = b.underlying 
          and a.expiration_date = b.expiration_date
where a.option_type = 'foo' 
and b.option_type = 'bar'
group by a.underlying, a.expiration_date
```

Comment: I have edit my question with an example based on your answer, but I am not sure how to formulate the inline calculations (spread_profit, spread_distance, spread_max_loss, spread_profit_ratio)

Comment: I would just go "old-school" and expand your terms right in place.  For example, spread_max_loss becomes (a.mid - b.mid) - (a.strike - b.strike).  Alternatively, I think you could write functions to do this in PL/pgSQL, but that's beyond my knowledge.